# ERROR Shutdown broker because none of the specified log dirs from

Tags: windows, apache-kafka

I have installed Kafka in windows system.

Below are some environment details:

**Kafka installation location**

`E:\kafka`

**zookeeper.properties**

`dataDir=E://kafka//zookeeper-data`

Also tried `dataDir=E:/kafka/zookeeper-data`

**server.properties**

`log.dirs= E://kafka//zookeeper-data//kafka-logs`

Also tried `log.dirs= E:/kafka/zookeeper-data/kafka-log`

**Using commands**

````
E:\kafka\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat ..\config\server.properties```

**Error*
[2021-12-11 19:04:57,403] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2021-12-11 19:04:57,405] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2021-12-11 19:04:57,406] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2021-12-11 19:04:57,406] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-ControllerMutation]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2021-12-11 19:04:57,425] INFO Log directory E:\kafka\zookeeper-data\kafka-logs not found, creating it. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2021-12-11 19:04:57,430] ERROR Failed to create or validate data directory E:\kafka\zookeeper-data\kafka-logs (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: E:\kafka\zookeeper-data
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:115)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:287)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:335)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.flushDir(Utils.java:953)
    at kafka.log.LogManager.$anonfun$createAndValidateLogDirs$1(LogManager.scala:159)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at kafka.log.LogManager.createAndValidateLogDirs(LogManager.scala:149)
    at kafka.log.LogManager.<init>(LogManager.scala:88)
    at kafka.log.LogManager$.apply(LogManager.scala:1283)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:254)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:109)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2021-12-11 19:04:57,435] ERROR Shutdown broker because none of the specified log dirs from E:\kafka\zookeeper-data\kafka-logs can be created or validated (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2021-12-11 19:04:57,979] WARN Close of session 0x1003af0a5840000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:377)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:324)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory$IOWorkRequest.doWork(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:522)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.WorkerService$ScheduledWorkRequest.run(WorkerService.java:154)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2021-12-11 19:05:16,043] INFO Expiring session 0x1003af0a5840000, timeout of 18000ms exceeded (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)`
````

Comment: Confluent recommend installing Kafka on WSL if you really must install it on a Windows environment - https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/.

Comment: FWIW, Zookeeper is its own process, therefore its logs should not be a subdirectory of "kafka data". Also Windows paths use (double) backslashes, not forward slashes

Comment: i have created separate directories for kafka and zookeeper logs and path added in servers.properties and zookepper properties with backslashess but stiil giving  ERROR Disk error while writing log start offsets checkpoint in directory E:\kafka\kafka-logs: Error while writing to checkpoint file E:\kafka\kafka-logs\log-start-offset-checkpoint (kafka.log.LogManager)